# How to Sign-In with Sharepoint from the Javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, ajax

I used the following code to access the sharepoint from javascript

```
var soapDataString = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                              <soap:Body> \
                                <Login xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                                  <username>testUser</username> \
                                  <password>testPwd</password> \
                                </Login> \
                              </soap:Body> \
                          </soap:Envelope>"

        // Call web service
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://abc-xyz-sp06/YY-SHAREPOINT/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapDataString,
            success: resultsFeedback,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });

function resultsFeedback(xData, status) {
    alert(xData);
    alert(status);
}
```

I followed from [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79803/how-to-authenticate-user-in-sharepoint-online-using-javascript) article. I even put the above code in the `ready` function. But the function not entering into `resultsFeedback` and nothing happens. I am not able to sign-in from the javascript.

Comment: Online or on premise? What SharePoint version?

Comment: I don't know the version but only the path we know. We are using that path to access the file. In Manual when we are given the path in the url, it asks for sign-in and after the credentials are given it displays the file(say for example, jpeg file)..Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to check what response do you get in fiddler when you make this request?Also, what is the version of jQuery you are referencing?

Comment: `error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown+'error login:' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }` Add this snippet to your code after success. You will find what actually the error is.

Comment: It only works for FBA. Not for Windows Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Use this url to access your resource when you do your first call to SharePoint

```
http://username:password@abc-xyz-sp06/YY-SHAREPOINT/YourResource.aspx
```

Regards