# Get data from a Sharepoint site for a web application

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, sharepoint-server, data, php

I would like to get data from the SharePoint site, but I don’t know if it is possible by using JavaScript or PHP or something else. After getting this and saving it in variables, I would do different stuff with it. Most of the data is related to agriculture.

I guess I would have to get connected to the SharePoint site and then access the different data tables. Probably the same idea as retrieving data from a different Database.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Please provide your detailed R&D on your problem that you have done. Some tried code chunk or other refereed link. Refer this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by multiple ways

i) JSOM

ii) CSOM

iii) REST API

You can do farther research.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798473.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx

**Go through Links for REST API**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/examples-of-office-365-unified-api-calls

https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/53/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access sharepoint data from outside of sharepoint, (ie in a .net application / android app etc), then you need to consume the `client object model` or the `web service` exposed by sharepoint.

[This Discussion](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79803/how-to-authenticate-user-in-sharepoint-online-using-javascript)  has a pretty detailed explanation towards using `authentication.asmx` to get a `token` that can be used for intearaction with sharepoint. You would need to pass credentials in order to get the token.

If you are looking to leverage the CSOM, sharepoint client side API, then you need to add, `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` and then proceed to initialize a context with `SharePointOnlineCredentails` for o365 enviornment, or `NetworkCredentials` for sharepoint On Premise enviorment.

You should go through links mentioned by **Kaushal** in order to get a better idea.