# populating SharePoint online lists into word task pane add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, word, add-ins

I am trying to build a word add-in in visual studio 2017.This add-in would ask for the SharePoint online SiteURL, username and password from a word documents  task pane and authenticate to SharePoint online. Then it would populate all lists from the SiteURL in the form of tree view. I am not able to authenticate using ClientID clientSecret and App domain. Please recommend right approach to connect to SharePoint online. Mainly i am looking for a JavaScript/rest api solution withour server side code.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you are trying to make use of Remote Authentication of SharePoint Online. You have basic details.

So you have to make use of the following web service call to authenticate SPO using non server side solution.

```
/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx
```

It will be a soap request.

You can refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/79811/52649) answer for in-depth information about remote authentication of SPO.